# RentCafe API JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get the data out of the response from RentCafe and I can't figure out how to iterate through it. I'm using curl and getting data back I just can't figure how to us it.

The data I'm getting back

```
[
    {
        "PropertyId": "785354",
        "FloorplanId": "2604197",
        "FloorplanName": "North 203",
        "Beds": "2",
        "Baths": "2.00",
        "MinimumSQFT": "0",
        "MaximumSQFT": "0",
        "MinimumRent": "-1",
        "MaximumRent": "-1",
        "MinimumDeposit": "750",
        "MaximumDeposit": "750",
        "AvailableUnitsCount": "0",
        "AvailabilityURL": "https://rentthemason.securecafe.com/onlineleasing/the-mason/oleapplication.aspx?stepname=Apartments&myOlePropertyId=785353&floorPlans=2604197",
        "FloorplanImageURL": "https://cdn.rentcafe.com/dmslivecafe/3/785353/Mason_North_203-403_2BR-2Bth-Balcony.png",
        "FloorplanImageName": "Mason_North_203-403_2BR-2Bth-Balcony.png",
        "FloorplanImageAltText": "",
        "PropertyShowsSpecials": "0",
        "FloorplanHasSpecials": "0",
        "UnitTypeMapping":"5379N203"
    },
    ...
]
```

Then I'm decoding it `$data = json_decode($result, true);` and using a `while` loop to go through and turn each part into a variable:

```
$bedrooms = $data["PropertyId"][$i]["Beds"];
```

But it's not working? All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Instead of a while loop, use a foreach loop.

   `foreach($data as $d) {
        /*access row info here, like $d['PropertyId'] or $d['Beds']*/
    }`

Comment: Thank you so much that seems to working can you explain why the while didn't work?

Comment: Not really since I can't see how you did it.